# net 8 blazor web app page refreshes after data loading

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

I have this page in dot net 8 blazor web app (has both server and client).

```
@page "/modifySpec/{SpecID}"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@attribute [StreamRendering()]

@using Corrugated_IO.Data
@using Corrugated_IO.Portal.Data

@inject CosmosDataSource cosmosDataSource
@inject NotificationService NotificationService
@inject DialogService DialogService

<h3>ManageSpecTemplates</h3>

@if (spec == null)
{
    <div>
        <RadzenProgressBarCircular Value="100" ShowValue="false" Mode="ProgressBarMode.Indeterminate" Size="ProgressBarCircularSize.Large" />
        <RadzenText TextStyle="TextStyle.Caption">Loading...</RadzenText>
    </div>
    return;
}

<RadzenRow>
    <RadzenColumn Size="6">
        <RadzenStack Orientation="Orientation.Vertical" >
            <RadzenRow >
                <RadzenColumn>
                    <RadzenText>Product ID: </RadzenText> <RadzenTextBox Value="@spec?.ProductId" Disabled="true" Style="width: 100%" />
                </RadzenColumn>
                <RadzenColumn Size="6">
                    <RadzenTextArea Value="@spec?.Description" Placeholder="Description" Style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />
                </RadzenColumn>
            </RadzenRow>
            <RadzenRow>
                <RadzenColumn Size="3"><RadzenText Text="Customer:" Style="margin-top: 10px" /></RadzenColumn>
                <RadzenColumn><RadzenTextBox Disabled="true" Style="width: 100%" Value="@spec.Customer.Name"/></RadzenColumn>
                <RadzenColumn><RadzenButton Text="Change" /><RadzenButton Text="Copy" /></RadzenColumn>
            </RadzenRow>
            <RadzenRow>
                <RadzenColumn Size="3"><RadzenText Style="margin-top: 10px" Text="Style:" /></RadzenColumn>
                <RadzenColumn><RadzenTextBox Disabled="true" Style="width: 100%" Value="@spec.CutStyle.Name" /></RadzenColumn>
                <RadzenColumn><RadzenButton Text="Change" /></RadzenColumn>
            </RadzenRow>
            <RadzenRow Style="height: 40px">
                <RadzenColumn Size="3"><RadzenText Text="Starting Material or Operation:" /></RadzenColumn>
                <RadzenColumn Size="2"><RadzenTextBox Disabled="true" Style="width: 100%" Value="@spec.StartingMaterial_Op" /></RadzenColumn>
                <RadzenColumn Size="2"><RadzenButton Text="Change" /></RadzenColumn>
                <RadzenColumn Size="4">
                    <RadzenStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal">
                        <RadzenText Text="Flute:" Style="margin-top: 10px" />
                        <RadzenDropDown Data=@flutes TValue="Flute" TextProperty="LetterGrade" @bind-Value="@selectedFlute" SelectedItem="@selectedFlute" Change="@(args => selectedFlute = (Flute)args)" Style="width: 50%" />
                    </RadzenStack>
                </RadzenColumn>
                
            </RadzenRow>
            <RadzenRow>
                <RadzenColumn><RadzenButton Text="Discard Changes" /></RadzenColumn>
                <RadzenColumn><RadzenButton Text="Estimate Spec" Style="float: right" /></RadzenColumn>
            </RadzenRow>
        </RadzenStack>
    </RadzenColumn>
    <RadzenColumn>
        
    </RadzenColumn>
    <RadzenColumn>

    </RadzenColumn>
</RadzenRow>
<RadzenRow>
    @* <CutStyleComponent /> *@
</RadzenRow>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string SpecID { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public Spec? spec { get; private set; }

    List<string> stringList = new List<string>{"Foo","Bar"};

    List<Flute> flutes = new List<Flute>();
    Flute selectedFlute = null;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        DefineFlutes();
        spec = await cosmosDataSource.GetSpec(SpecID);

        if(spec is null)
        {
            NotificationService.Notify(NotificationSeverity.Error, "Spec ID not Found", $"Spec ID ({SpecID}) was not found", 30000);
        }
    }
    

    public async Task ChangeCutStyle()
    {
        
    }

    private void DefineFlutes()
    {
        flutes.AddRange(new[]{
            new Flute
            {
                LetterGrade = 'A',
                FlutesPerFoot = 33,
                Thickness = 0.1875m
            },
            new Flute
            {
                LetterGrade = 'B',
                FlutesPerFoot = 47,
                Thickness = 0.125m
            },
            new Flute
            {
                LetterGrade = 'C',
                FlutesPerFoot = 38,
                Thickness = 0.15625m
            },
            new Flute
            {
                LetterGrade = 'E',
                FlutesPerFoot = 90,
                Thickness = 0.0625m
            },
            new Flute
            {
                LetterGrade = 'F',
                FlutesPerFoot = 125,
                Thickness = 0.03125m
            }
        });
    }

}
```

the page loads the data from local cosmos. then as soon as it loads and renders, the very next millisecond, it clears the view and goes back to as if I just navigated to it.

Why is it re-loading the view and how do I stop this behavior?

Edit: When I comment out the `@rendermode InteractiveServer` on line 2 it doesn't reload the view, but I lose my server interactivity and I don't know why. if i change it to `InteractiveWebAssembly`, it doesn't reload, but I get the error: `Error: One or more errors occurred. (Root component type 'Corrugated_IO.Portal.Components.Pages.ModifySpec' could not be found in the assembly 'Portal'.)` and there is no interactivity. Same with `InteractivityAuto`

Comment: Watch the release video.

Comment: i've watched a few videos trying to figure this out. Do you have one in particular or something more helpful that can guide me in what i'm looking for?